# Functional construction of a List from Pair-s

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I try to construct a list from a primitive Pair data (see [implementation](https://github.com/ghita/SICP-js/blob/master/ch-2/pair.js) for full implementation) 
The constructor function uses recursion and is affected by stack space limitation for this reason. One possible solution is pass the (array, decrementing array index, incremental list) and keep state as part of the recursive call, but this still uses space at runtime.

Is there a way to implement this tail recursive  ? I run this in Node.

```
// listIter::[xs] -> List[xs]
export function listIter(xs) {
    const construct = (list, index) => {
        return (index === -1) ?
            list :
            construct(pair(xs[index], list), index - 1);
    }

    return construct(Pair.empty(), xs.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Last time I checked Node removed the tail recursion optimisation for some technical reasons. I don't know if they reinstated it. Just something to be aware of - it's possible that tail recursion doesn't solve the issue. You can look into trampolines as an alternative.

Comment: The recursive step in your algorithm is in tail position, right?

Comment: @bob recursive step is in incrementally building the list argument. This is contructed in an "iterative" manner.

Comment: Yes, it builds the data structure on the way forward. Technically it is recursion accumulator style or corecursion, if I am not mistaken. Either way you need space at runtime on the way forward or on the way back.

Comment: Your `Pair.of` and `Pair.empty` functions don't make sense. There's no empty pair, and you cannot construct a pair from a single value. They at best make sense for a list, but then they should look different.

Comment: @Bergi "static of" makes sense, it's just a constructor, no need to call "new Ctor". Empty needs to exist, where to put that is debatable.

Comment: @Ghita An `of` function does, by convention and [in the js fp community](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#fantasy-landof-method), take only a single argument. If you want to make a static factory method, you should name it differently. Your `export function pair` already does a fine job there - just drop the `of` method. Regarding empty, if you meant that to represent the end of the list (`Nil`), you should use a value that is not a `Pair` instance - either a sentinel object or just the value `null`.

Comment: @Beri Thanks for pointing out about of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SICP is a wonderful text. The code here should be fairly self-explanatory. I'm short on time at the moment but I'll follow up later today to add some details and answer potential follow-up questions -

---

**main.js**

```js
// main.js
import { of, fromArray, toString } from './list'

toString(of(999))
// 999->Empty.

toString(fromArray([]))
// Empty.

toString(fromArray([1]))
// 1->Empty.

toString(fromArray([1,2,3,4]))
// 1->2->3->4->Empty.

const big =
  Array.from(Array(100000), (_, x) => x)

toString(fromArray(big))
// 0->1->2->3->...99999->Empty.
```

---

**list.js**

```js
import { loop, recur } from './function'

const empty =                      // <-- empty list
  Symbol()                         // <-- any sentinel value

const pair = (left, right) =>      // <-- pair constructor
  ({ pair, left, right })          // <-- plain object

const of = (x = null) =>           // <-- "of" constructor
  pair(x, empty)                   // <-- singleton list

const fromArray = (xs = []) =>
  loop                             // <-- begin loop
    ( ( r = empty                  // <-- init r
      , i = 0                      // <-- init i
      ) =>                         // <-- loop body
        i >= xs.length             // <-- exit condition
          ? reverse(r)             // <-- tail; return
          : recur                  // <-- tail; recur
              ( pair(xs[i], r)     // <-- next r
              , i + 1              // <-- next i
              )
    )

const reverse = (node = empty) =>
  loop                             // <-- begin loop
    ( ( r = empty                  // <-- init r
      , t = node                   // <-- init t
      ) =>                         // <-- loop body
        t === empty                // <-- exit condition
          ? r                      // <-- tail; return
          : recur                  // <-- tail; recur
              ( pair(t.left, r)    // <-- next r
              , t.right            // <-- next t
              )
    )

const toString = (node = empty) =>
  loop                             // <-- begin loop
    ( ( r = "Empty."               // <-- init r
      , t = reverse(node)          // <-- init t
      ) =>                         // <-- loop body
      t === empty                  // <-- exit condition
        ? r                        // <-- tail; return
        : recur                    // <-- tail; recur
            ( t.left + "->" + r    // <-- next r
            , t.right              // <-- next t
            )
    )

// "pair" is not exported
// it is an implementation detail of our list module
export { empty, of, fromArray, reverse, toString }
```

---

**function.js**

```js
const identity = x => x

const recur = (...v) =>
  ({ recur, [Symbol.iterator]: _ => v.values() })

const loop = (f = identity, ...init) =>
  whileTrue               // <-- functional while
    ( r => r && r.recur   // <-- while condition
    , r => f(...r)        // <-- next r
    , f(...init)          // <-- init r
    )

const whileTrue = (test = identity, next = identity, r = null) =>
{ while(Boolean(test(r))) // <-- while test(r) is true
    r = next(r)           // <-- nexr r
  return r                // <-- return r
}

export { identity, loop, recur, whileTrue }
```

---

**demo**

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
// function.js -------
const identity = x => x

const recur = (...v) =>
  ({ recur, [Symbol.iterator]: _ => v.values() })

const loop = (f = identity, ...init) =>
  whileTrue
    ( r => r && r.recur
    , r => f(...r)
    , f(...init)
    )

const whileTrue = (test = identity, next = identity, r = null) =>
{ while(Boolean(test(r)))
    r = next(r)
  return r
}

// list.js -------
const empty =
  Symbol()

const pair = (left, right) =>
  ({ pair, left, right })

const of = (x = null) =>
  pair(x, empty)

const fromArray = (xs = []) =>
  loop
    ( ( r = empty
      , i = 0
      ) =>
        i >= xs.length
          ? reverse(r)
          : recur
              ( pair(xs[i], r)
              , i + 1
              )
    )

const reverse = (node = empty) =>
  loop
    ( ( r = empty
      , t = node
      ) =>
        t === empty
          ? r
          : recur
              ( pair(t.left, r)
              , t.right
              )
    )

const toString = (node = empty) =>
  loop
    ( ( r = "Empty."
      , t = reverse(node)
      ) =>
      t === empty
        ? r
        : recur
            ( t.left + "->" + r
            , t.right
            )
    )

// main.js -------
console.log(toString(of(999)))
// 999->Empty.

console.log(toString(fromArray([])))
// Empty.

console.log(toString(fromArray([1])))
// 1->Empty.

console.log(toString(fromArray([1,2,3,4])))
// 1->2->3->4->Empty.

const big =
  Array.from(Array(100000), (_, x) => x)

console.log(toString(fromArray(big)))
// 0->1->2->3->...99999->Empty.
```

---

**further abstraction**

With more time earlier I probably would've written `pair` as its own module -

```js
// pair.js
import { raise } from './function'

const empty =
  Symbol()

const pair = (left, right) =>
  ({ pair, left, right })

const left = (t = empty) =>
  t === empty
    ? raise(`cannot read value from empty`)
    : t.left

const right = (t = empty) =>
  t === empty
    ? raise(`cannot read value from empty`)
    : t.right

const of = ([ left, right ]) =>
  pair(left, right)

export { empty, pair, left, right, of }
```

Adding `raise` to `function` module -

```js
// function.js
const identity = //

const recur = //

const loop = //

const whileTrue = //

const raise = (msg = "") => // functional throw
  { throw Error(msg) }

export { identity, loop, recur, whileTrue, raise }
```

Creating a better abstraction barrier between `list` module and `pair` module -

```js
// list.js
import { loop, recur } from './function'
import { empty, pair, left, right } from './pair'

const of = (x = null) =>
  pair(x, empty)                   // <-- pair, empty

const fromArray = (xs = []) =>
  loop
    ( ( r = empty                  // <-- empty
      , i = 0
      ) =>
        i >= xs.length
          ? reverse(r)
          : recur
              ( pair(xs[i], r)     // <-- pair
              , i + 1              //
              )
    )

const reverse = (node = empty) =>
  loop
    ( ( r = empty                  // <-- empty
      , t = node
      ) =>
        t === empty                // <-- empty
          ? r
          : recur
              ( pair(left(t), r)   // <-- pair, left
              , right(t)           // <-- right
              )
    )

const toString = (node = empty) =>
  loop
    ( ( r = "Empty."
      , t = reverse(node)
      ) =>
      t === empty                  // <-- empty
        ? r
        : recur
            ( left(t) + "->" + r   // <-- left
            , right(t)             // <-- right
            )
    )

// re-export empty
// it's okay that List.empty and Pair.empty are
// represented using the same sentinel value
export { empty, of, fromArray, reverse, toString }
```

It's nice to see writing `pair` as a separate step because it shows us how to break apart modules when data structures become too entangled.

Comment: Thanks for your time ! "fairly self-explanatory" :-)

Comment: You're welcome Ghita. I added some more inline comments and a new section including a separated `pair` module.